# DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID error with PayPal Android SDK

Tags: android, paypal-sandbox

> 2020-01-27 15:51:32.312 1732-1903/com.example.paypalnewdemo
>   E/paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:400,exception:
>   2020-01-27 15:51:32.317 1732-1903/com.example.paypalnewdemo
>   E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server
>   response:{"name":"DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID","message":"PayPal-Request-Id
>   header was already
>   used.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"882e8b0d78934"}
>   2020-01-27 15:51:32.318 1732-1732/com.example.paypalnewdemo
>   E/paypal.sdk: DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID

Answer (score 1):

What's the question? If you would like some useful help, we need more information!

Answer (score 1):

[Here you can find PayPal's documentation on API idempotency and use of the PayPal-Request-Id header](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/#api-idempotency)

Try to resubmit your request in a way that doesn't duplicate that header for new requests, when it shouldn't.

Comment: But how can you give me an example